# ¿Cómo cargar distintos arrays ingresados dentro de un mismo modal de Bootstrap con JavaScript o jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, array, bootstrap, modal

He estado intentado cargar datos de Documentos de tipo Referencia que deben ser ingresados y cargados en una tabla dentro de un mismo modal de Bootstrap. Los datos que se deben cargar en la tabla vienen de tres inputs del modal. El problema a la hora de cargar es que los datos en la tabla aparecen como "undefined":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi JavaScript y HTML. Estoy utilizando dos funciones, GuardarDocumentoReferencia() que obtiene los valores ingresados en los inputs, y EscribirListaDocumentosReferencias() que obtiene los datos y los ingresa incrustando HTML con una plantilla. Debajo está mi fragmento HTML que contiene el la información del modal junto a inputs y la tabla que recibe las incrustaciones de HTML del JavaScript:

```js
function GuardarDocumentoReferencia() {

  let numerador = 0;
  let identificadorDocumentoReferencia = $("#listaDocumentoReferencias").val();
  let numeroDocumentoReferencia = $("#numeroDocumentoReferencia").val();
  let fechaDocumentoReferencia = $("#fechaDocumentoReferencia").val();

  let documentoReferencia = [{
    "numerador": numerador,
    "identificadorReferencia": identificadorDocumentoReferencia,
    "numeroDocumentoReferencia": numeroDocumentoReferencia,
    "fechaDocumentoReferencia": fechaDocumentoReferencia
  }];

  let listaDocumentosReferencias = [];

  listaDocumentosReferencias.push(documentoReferencia);

  for (let i = 0; i < listaDocumentosReferencias.length; i++) {

    listaDocumentosReferencias[i].numerador = i;
  }

  sessionStorage.setItem("listaDocumentosReferencias", JSON.stringify(listaDocumentosReferencias));


  EscribirListaDocumentosReferencias();
}

function EscribirListaDocumentosReferencias() {

  let listaDocumentosReferencias = [];
  x = sessionStorage.getItem("listaDocumentosReferencias");
  listaDocumentosReferencias = JSON.parse(x);

  plantilla = "";

  for (let i = 0; i < listaDocumentosReferencias.length; i++) {
    plantilla += `
            <tr>
                <td>${listaDocumentoReferencias[i].identificadorReferencia}</td>
                <td>${listaDocumentoReferencias[i].numeroDocumentoReferencia}</td>
                <td>${listaDocumentoReferencias[i].fechaDocumentoReferencia}</td>
                <td><input class='form-control' style='background-color: crimson; color: white; font-size: 10px; text-align: center;' value='X'></td>
            </tr>`;
  }

  $("#tablaDocumentoReferencias").html(plantilla);
  $("#listaDocumentoReferencias").val();
  $("#numeroDocumentoReferencia").val(0);
  $("#fechaDocumentoReferencia").val(new Date().toISOString().substring(0, 10));
}
```

```html
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" id="panelDocumentosReferencias">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Documentos de Referencia</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <label for="listaReferencias">Documento de Referencia:</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="listaDocumentoReferencias">
          <option selected value="Seleccione un Documento de Referencia">Seleccione un Documento de Referencia</option>
        </select>
        <label for="numeroReferencia">N° de Referencia:</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="numeroDocumentoReferencia" type="number" value="0">
        <label for="fechaReferencia">Fecha:</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="fechaDocumentoReferencia" type="date"><br>
        <div class="form-control" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
          <table class="table table-responsive" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%;">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Código de Documento</th>
                <th>N° Documento</th>
                <th>Fecha de Documento</th>
                <th>Quitar</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
          </table>
          <div style="height: 100px; overflow-y: scroll; width: 100%;">
            <table class="table" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%;">
              <tbody id="tablaDocumentoReferencias"></tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="botonGuardarReferencia" onclick="GuardarDocumentoReferencia()">Guardar Referencia</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Si alguien me pudiera ayudar me salvaría la vida, quizás me estoy equivocando en algo que no he visto o por ser información cargada en el modal se debe hacer un procedimiento distinto. De antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Detecto varias cosas raras que creo que puedes arreglar de este modo:

1. Cambia esto:

```
let documentoReferencia = [{
    "numerador": numerador,
    "identificadorReferencia": identificadorDocumentoReferencia,
    "numeroDocumentoReferencia": numeroDocumentoReferencia,
    "fechaDocumentoReferencia": fechaDocumentoReferencia
  }];
```

por esto:

```
let documentoReferencia = {
    "numerador": numerador,
    "identificadorReferencia": identificadorDocumentoReferencia,
    "numeroDocumentoReferencia": numeroDocumentoReferencia,
    "fechaDocumentoReferencia": fechaDocumentoReferencia
  };
```

pues luego estas haciendo un push de esa variable en otra array, y ya serian demasiadas arrays y el for que muestro a continuación no te funcionaria tampoco:

```
for (let i = 0; i < listaDocumentosReferencias.length; i++) {
```

2. Tienes un error tipográfico en estas lineas:

```
<td>${listaDocumentoReferencias[i].identificadorReferencia}</td>
<td>${listaDocumentoReferencias[i].numeroDocumentoReferencia}</td>
<td>${listaDocumentoReferencias[i].fechaDocumentoReferencia}</td>
```

que deberias modificar por estas:

```
<td>${listaDocumentosReferencias[i].identificadorReferencia}</td>
<td>${listaDocumentosReferencias[i].numeroDocumentoReferencia}</td>
<td>${listaDocumentosReferencias[i].fechaDocumentoReferencia}</td>
```

pues te has comido una `s` por el camino y de ahí el `undefined`.

Prueba a ver si eso te ayuda a continuar y si queda algo pendiente lo dices.